# Why I don't close browser by webdriver?

Tags: java, windows, internet-explorer, intellij-idea, selenium-webdriver

Could someone explain me why method in section @After don't close browser after test?

```
package TestCases;

import junit.framework.Assert;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

public class ScriptCase {

    private WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void startWeb() {
        WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

        driver.navigate().to("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.recursify.pixstack.free&hl=en");
    }

    @After
    public void ShutdownWeb() {
        driver.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void startWebDriver(){

        Assert.assertTrue("Title is different from expected",
                driver.getTitle().startsWith("PixStack Photo Editor Free"));

    }
}
```

When I move code from @After directly in section @Test (to the end) my project closes browser successfully. Project is compiled good.

Comment: try this instead `driver.browser.close`

Comment: 2 Martin Larsson:
I've got hint: cannot resolve symbol 'browser'

Comment: driver.quit() closes all the webdriver instances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using @ Before you can try...

```
      @BeforeClass 
    baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/";
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get(baseUrl);

and @AfterClass
  driver.quit();
```

So try using this it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

In your example code, you have two different `driver` variables. One is local to the `startWeb` method, and is used to create your instance of the browser. The other variable is at the class level, and is never instantiated. This is is the instance you're attempting to use in your `ShutdownWeb` method. To resolve this, do not re-declare a local `driver` variable in your setup method. To wit:

```
public class ScriptCase {

  private WebDriver driver;

  @Before
  public void startWeb() {
    // This is the line of code that has changed. By removing
    // the type "WebDriver", the statement changes from declaring
    // a new local-scope variable to use of the already declared
    // class scope variable of the same name.
    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    driver.navigate().to("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.recursify.pixstack.free&hl=en");
  }

  @After
  public void shutdownWeb() {
    driver.quit();
  }

  @Test
  public void startWebDriver(){

    Assert.assertTrue("Title is different from expected", driver.getTitle().startsWith("PixStack Photo Editor Free"));

  }
}
```

Additionally, the advice to use the `quit` method instead of `close` is sound, and I have included that change in my code above.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ScriptCase {

    private WebDriver driver;

   @BeforeClass 
    public void startWeb() {
       driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(); 
       driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       driver.navigate().to("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.recursify.pixstack.free&hl=en");
    }

    @AfterClass 
    public void ShutdownWeb() {
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
    }

    @Test
    public void startWebDriver(){

        Assert.assertTrue("Title is different from expected",
                driver.getTitle().startsWith("PixStack Photo Editor Free"));

    }
}
```

Try This..... it works